# Rename Days of the Week in Windows

Tags: windows, calendar

Is there a way that I can rename the days of the week in Windows? For example, (just an example...) rename Sunday so that it will say "First" instead? I set the settings so that it puts the day of the week with the dates too, but I want to change what it says. Thanks.

Comment: Omg, I really would love to do this too! Someone, answer this question quick! >.<

Comment: Where exactly do you want to change this? When you click on the clock? That isn't a setting that can be configured and I don't see why anyone would. Even if you wanted to, it would be difficult as @Keltari mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.

The names of the days are hardcoded strings in the code.  While it *might* actually be technically possible to search through all of Windows applications, DLLs, etc. change the strings you will most likely break functionality of other applications that are looking for the proper names of the days of the week.

Comment: So there is no way that you can change the language or something? That is my ultimate goal with this, however I have already found that if you set a language of the calendar, other programs that try to find your computer language will think that your computer language is your calendar language so I am unable to read the messages.. Instead I have just put all of the special things about the language as my settings for the default language so that other programs still use English, but the clock doesn't. Is there no way of changing the days of the week too for this to work? (Or another method)

Comment: If you change the language of the whole computer, it would change the language of the clock. You cannot give your weekdays an arbitrary value though. This is controlled deep in the system and would be difficult to find and edit as @Keltari mentioned.

Comment: @MC10 I did not change the language of the computer. Sorry that wasn't very clear. What I did, is I went to the region settings where it has the tabs Formats, Location and Administrative. Then I changed the dropdown box under Format: to Japanese. I then setup the clock and everything the way I wanted, but other programs that try to get the display language to make it easier for you think it's Japanese. I am pretty sure that is not the system language. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: So you would like to change the format of the clock without changing the language?

Comment: @MC10 Because like I said, I am unable to read 100% of what programs say when they automatically set the language to Japanese, but I like the Japanese clock/date and time format better than English. When I set the format to Japanese, other programs (like Dropbox or Google Earth) will automatically set the language to Japanese so then I have to figure out how I can change it back to English. Some programs don't even have the option to change the language too.

Comment: try search in registry for days of week, see where windows keeping them, maybe u can rename from there, but i dont think so. its probably hard coded

Comment: @Josh You can change the format of date/time without changing language but this would require you to do it manually in the Settings. Would that be enough for your purposes? You could change it so that it looks like the Japanese format.

Comment: @MC10 This is probably what I have already done, but if possible I would like to have the days of the week renamed to match too. Otherwise, (like now) it will read 15/07/30 (Thu) which is a bit strange seeing the English name in the Japanese format... :/ I don't see anything in the registry either. Thanks for the suggestion though.